# How to decide if a model was trained by a sample?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, hdf5, training-data

I have 2 trained models (hdf5) and a list of 100 samples (npy) from the MNIST dataset.
Model 1 was trained by 50 samples and model 2 by the other 50.

Now my Question is if it's possible to decide which model was trained by which sample.

I'm pretty new to Python and have no glue how to manage that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no definite way to tell given *only* the models and the 100 data-points.
But you can make an educated guess based on any over-fit if such exists.
Basically, if there's any over-fit, then the model trained on the "first" 50 images, will give better results on those 50 than on the other 50 "validation" images. And the same applies to your second model.
*So*... you can look at the discrepancy of each model on each of the 50-image sets, and maybe, just maybe, you'll see a consistent bias towards the training set of each model.
But that's only statistical, and based on some wishful thinking.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

*If* you know how samples were used (e.g. first 50 samples go to train one model, the other 50 the other) the following may help you.

Training means to find the parameters that reduce the cost function in a given error. So you will only need to test each model in each sample. The sample that gives you back the smallest error is the one that was used to train that model.

So if you create a table of the form

```
          +----------+----------+
          | model 1  | model 2  |
+---------+----------+----------+
|sample 1 |  e11     | e12      |
+---------+----------+----------+
|sample 2 |  e21     | e22      |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

The row with the smallest value at a given column is the sample used to train that column

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information?
It looks like you are trying to do some machine learning in python. 
- which library are you using? (pytorch, tensorflow..)
- how are your sample fed into the net?in pytorch for instance you have to implement your version of a data loader class..

Any piece of code is also useful for others to understand what you want to do and what is your problem.
In an attempt to answer your vague question: generally speaking you can divide the training set (with N samples) into two folders (one with the first N/2 and the other with the remaining N/2) and feed each network with the two different sub-training set.